# Hiding New Friends Activity on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a privacy setting on Facebook that will stop the posting that is made on your friend's wall when you make a new friend?

I do not want this to appear on my friend's wall when I make a new friend
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a setting that will prevent you from appearing on your *friend's* wall, but you can control what shows up on *your own* profile (via [Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=111039288984510)):

> You cannot completely turn off Recent
>   Activity stories; however, you can:
>
> - Prevent people from seeing certain Recent Activity stories on your
>     profile by editing individual privacy
>     settings.
> - Remove Recent Activity stories by clicking the "Remove" button that
>     appears to the right of the story
>     after you move your mouse over it.

You can also find more information about preventing people from seeing recent activity stories from [this Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=146672188738981).

Answer (score 1):

See if the [Better Facebook Extension](http://betterfacebook.net) works for you.

It should automatically remove new actvity, but I am not sure if you are able to filter which activity is posted.

[image: Steps to remove]

Comment: Link seems to be redirecting to [social fixed](http://socialfixer.com/) now